# Laravel - Is it possible to make relation between models (belongsTo) via an element of array as text in table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm absolute beginner in Laravel.

Is it possible to make relation, say belongsTo between models via an element of array.

Column in table1 like this:

```
mapping: ["misc","rates","photos"]
```

I need something similar to following:

```
public function dependencies() : BelongsTo
{
    // This is impossible because "mapping" is array in Depends model and text type in database.
    return $this->belongsTo(Depends::class, 'mapping', 'element_of_array'); 
}
```

or something similar (hasMany etc).

Table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `dependings` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`media_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`type` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`mapping` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `dependent_collection_mappings_collection_id_type_unique` (`media_id`,`type`),
CONSTRAINT `dependent_collection_mappings_collection_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`media_id`) REFERENCES `media` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Could you explain further your wanted end result so we might be able to provide some help.

Comment: `mapping` is of text type not array type so probably not possible unless the underlying DBMS has a native array type that supports this